# How do I use a function to catch a repetetive exceptions instead of writing same code in except

Tags: python, exception, shutil

Currently, I have a program that deletes a few files, copies new files, and renames stuff. I want the program to continue to work normally even if one of the files don't get copied and throw an exception. I am using following code to handle exceptions:

```
try:
    print("Removing old file...")
    ('W:/My Documents/test.exe')
    print("Success!")

#Remove old file in W drive - EXCEPTION HANDLING
except WindowsError as e:
    if e.winerror == 3 or e.winerror == 2:
        print("Requested file does not exist.")
    elif e.winerror == 5:
        print("You do not have the required privilages to make changes to this file.")
        print("One of the following solutions may work:")
        print("   >The file might be open in another location, close the file and try again.")
        print("   >Try to run the program as administrator.")
        print("   >Change file security to allow read/write access to "+userName+".")
    else:
        print("Unexpected exception occured. Please copy the following exception and send it to xxx at xxx@abc")
        print(e)
        print("Program will try to continue")
except Exception as e:
    print("Unexpected exception occured. Please copy the following exception and send it to xxx at xxx@abc")
    print(e)
    print("Program will try to continue")
```

Problem is, there 5 different sets of files that I want the program to individually try to copy and all of them have the same exception handling.

My question is, can I make a function that handles these repetitive exceptions? Or another way that doesn't make my program 70% exception handling.

Comment: Just define a function to remove the file passed to it as an argument and put the exception handling in *that* and then call this function 5 times.

Comment: @martineau That's a great idea. I might have to add another argument to tell the function weather to copy, rename, delete or move but it shouldn't be too hard. Thanks

Comment: Sure, add whatever arguments are needed to handle all the variations.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out. Apparently, I can pass the Exception to a function and use it however I want. I did something like this:

```
def winErrorHandling(e):
    if e.winerror == 3 or e.winerror == 2:
        print("Requested file does not exist.")
    elif e.winerror == 5:
        print("You do not have the required privilages to make changes to this file.")
        print("One of the following solutions may work:")
        print("   >The file might be open in another location, close the file and try again.")
        print("   >Try to run the program as administrator.")
        print("   >Change file security to allow read/write access to ")#+userName+".")
    else:
        print("")
        print(e)
```

And try block being something like:

```
try:
    print("Removing old profile backup...")
    shutil.rmtree('C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/a')
    print("Success!")
#EXCEPTION HANDLING #TODO
except WindowsError as e:
    winErrorHandling(e)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```